# Assassin multiclass feat for Shade Form

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers, assassin

Is there an Assassin multiclass feat that grants Shade Form? I found one for Assassin's Shroud and Shadow Step but I can't find one for Shade Form.

Comment: Sidebar: essentials assassin is a much better assassin.

Answer (score 5):

There is one, but it's not useful:

Iff you paragon multiclass, [Darkened Soul](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2834) allows you to gain the class feature Shade Form.

Answer (score 4):

**There isn't one.**

Pre-Essentials Assassins have very, *very* little feat support, including in the multiclass department. And even the core classes don't have multiclass feats to mimic *all* their class features.